# Understanding controllability indices

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I'm teaching myself linear control systems through various online materials and the book *Linear Systems Theory and Design* by Chen. I'm trying to understand controllability indices. Chen says that looking at the controllability matrix $C$ as follows

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix} B & AB & A^2 B & \cdots & A^n B \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 & \cdots & b_p & | & A b_1 & \cdots & A b_p & | & \cdots & | & A^{n-1} b_1 & \cdots & A^{n-1} b_p \end{bmatrix}$$

that reading left to right, the columns are linearly independent until some column $A^ib_m$, which is dependent on the columns to the left - this makes sense - but that subsequent columns associated with $b_m$ (e.g. $A^{i+k}b_m$) are also linearly dependent on their proceeding columns, or that "once a column associated with $b_m$ becomes linearly dependent, then all columns associated with $b_m$ thereafter are linearly dependent". Unfortunately this last point isn't intuitive to me at all - if anyone can shed some light on this or help me see it I'd be very grateful!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Luke

Answer (score 1):

I am studying the same subject now, from the same book and had exactly the same question you had.

The answer by @Pait doesn't show that the resulting set $\mathit{\lambda_iAb_i}$ is a subset of the LHS vectors relative to $\mathit{A^2b_1}$ in the controllability matrix. However I had understood it myself, and I will post it here for reference.

Say $\pmb{A^ib_m}$ is the first vector associated with $\pmb{b_m}$ that is dependent on some of the vectors $\pmb{v_k}$ at its left hand side (LHS).

That is: $$\pmb{A^ib_m}= \sum_{k=1}^{i*m-1}\alpha_k\pmb{v_k} \ \ \ (1)$$
Now, for the next vector associated with $\pmb{b_m}$, i.e. $\pmb{A^{i+1}b_m}$, we have: $$\pmb{A^{i+1}b_m}= \sum_{k=1}^{i*m-1}\alpha_k\pmb{Av_k} \ \ \ (2)$$
Now we show (or clarify) that the set $\{\pmb{Av_k}\ |\ k\in\Bbb{Z},\ 1\le k \le (i*m-1)\}$ is a subset of the vectors at LHS of $\pmb{A^{i+1}b_m}$ in the controllability matrix.

The sum in (1) can be split into:
$$\pmb{A^ib_m} = \underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}\alpha_{mk}^{'}\pmb{A^kb_m}}_{Vectors\ which\ are\\ associated\ with\ \pmb{b_m}\\ but\ are\ on\ LHS} + \underbrace{(\sum_{k=0}^i\alpha_{1k}^{'}\pmb{A^kb_1} +\sum_{k=0}^i\alpha_{2k}^{'}\pmb{A^kb_2}+\cdots+\sum_{k=0}^i\alpha_{(m-1)k}^{'}\pmb{A^kb_{m-1}})}_{Vectors\ associated\ with\ \pmb{b_j}\ columns\\ which\ are\ before\ \pmb{b_m}\ in\ the\ \pmb{B}\ matrix}$$

Now by multiplying by $\pmb{A}$ on both sides:
$$\pmb{A^{i+1}b_m} = \sum_{k=1}^{i}\alpha_{mk}^{'}\pmb{A^kb_m} + (\sum_{k=1}^{i+1}\alpha_{1k}^{'}\pmb{A^kb_1} +\sum_{k=1}^{i+1}\alpha_{2k}^{'}\pmb{A^kb_2}+\cdots+\sum_{k=1}^{i+1}\alpha_{(m-1)k}^{'}\pmb{A^kb_{m-1}})$$
Clearly, the vectors in the summations are subset of the vectors that are at LHS of $\pmb{A^{i+1}b_m}$ in the controllability matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Say $A b_1$ is linearly dependent on the $b_i$, namely $A b_1 = \lambda_i b_i$ (summation implicit). Then $A^2 b_1 = A \lambda_i b_i = \lambda_i A b_i$, so $A^2 b_1$ depends linearly on the columns $A b_i$ which are on its left.

Comment: I think this answers your question perfectly. I just want to add some intuition as I had too difficulties understanding controllability indices. The $i$th controllability index gives the dimension of the reachable space by only using the $i$th input that is not reachable by using previous inputs. Therefore, if the system is controllable, the sum of the controllability indices are $n$.

Comment: Right. Notice also that the initial ordering of the inputs may affect the list of indices.

Comment: Yes, it may affect the ordering of the indices but the values are invariant under the ordering of the inputs.

Comment: That is true. However they are not invariant under ordering of the columns of the controllability matrix, which itself is arbitrary.

We're getting away from the original question but I do find this issue confusing, so it's useful to register that the concepts are indeed not completely transparent.